# jupyterlab-myst: how to automatically popup tooltip when hovering over the footnote label?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, myst

I am using [jupyterlab-myst](https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab-myst/), a really cool extension.

The [Footnotes section in MyST documentation](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/typography.html#footnotes) has some examples.  When I hover over the footnote label, the footnote definition together with the label automatically popup, like a tooltip.

I copied the markdown text from the example in [Footnotes](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/synta/typography.html#footnotes) into a markdown cell of my jupyter notebook and got jupyterlab-myst to render the markdown.  When I hover over the footnote label, I expect the footnote label and the footnote definition to appear in a popup box and I expect that box to automatically popup.  However, what I got is a "circled-plus" (see-more) icon that looks like a magnifying glass.  I need to click the mouse for the footnote definition to popup and the popup does not show the footnote label, only the definition.

How can I have the tooltip-like automatic popup behavior?  How can I make the popup show the label as well?

Can somebody with 1500 or more reputation create the jupyterlab-myst tag?  Sheesh!  I am not asking about MyST, I am asking about jupyterlab-myst.

Comment: I don't know what enables that feature, but perhaps it is `myst_footnote_transition`? This is a MyST extension. See https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#global-configuration. It might also be this extension: https://sphinx-tippy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I have been looking for the `conf.py` in my JupyterLab folder without success.  I think it is a different filename in Jupyter since Jupyter has lots of extensions and each extension has its own `.json` config file.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the package [`sphinx-tippy`](https://sphinx-tippy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
According to this [comment](https://github.com/executablebooks/jupyter-book/issues/1297#issuecomment-1383098228) on [jupyter-book](https://github.com/executablebooks/jupyter-book)'s GitHub repo, `sphinx-tippy` is what is being used in the official MyST documentation webpage.

```bash
pip install sphinx-tippy
```

and

```py
extensions = ["sphinx_tippy"]
```

A nice alternative depending your usecase might also be [`sphinx-hoverxref`](https://sphinx-hoverxref.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).